# MathJax and php

Tags: php, mathjax

I have installed Apache and PHP on my Mac and I am using it as webserver to write some web pages that contain MathJax.

Everything works fine as long as it is on my Mac. I am having the MathJax processed by the cdn.mathjax.org server (I am not using a local installation).

But when I move the site to a remote server, the MathJax does not work. I have tried two different remote servers with same result.

I have found that if I change the extension of my files from .php to .html, then MathJax works fine on the remote servers, but then the php content of course does not work.  And the php content also works well on the remote servers if the filename is .php.

So it seems that I can get either php to work on the remote server, or MathJax, but not both...but both work well locally on my Mac.

I am rather stuck and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well if I got to mathjax.org it shows this message `The MathJax CDN shut down on April 30, 2017!` Not sure if that's your problem or not though. I have never used it.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that but I think there is a re-direct to a new server, and in any case MathJax using that CDN address works fine as long as the file extension is html.

Comment: I have now solved this issue, with help from Davide Cervone, so I thought I would report it. The problem was that MathJax was called explicitly in the <head> section of my .php files, but then it was called again implicitly by the latexmathjax.js file, and this caused all sorts of synchronization problems. To solve the problem, it was enough to remove the explicit call to MathJax in the <head> section of my php files, and let latexmathjax.js do the calling. A note to point out this possible problem to other users of latexmathjax.js has now been added to to documentation for latexmathjax.js